# Display yellow square on hover panel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display the yellow square (that is a glyphicon of bootstrap but i don't know why it's doesn't show) when the user hover the panel, and hide when the user leave the cursor of the panel. The main class is .panel.

The structure of the panel:

```
  <div id="taskPanel" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div id="13" class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></div>
       <div style="float: left;margin-left: 15px;">Task 13</div>
     <div style="margin-left: 30px;width: 96%;">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow"></span>
<div class="miniswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="13" checked>
    <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
</div> 
  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-id="13">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">  
        <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <strong>URI:</strong>&nbsp;/cron/test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

A JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yRhD/

Comment: Add the code that you have tried here so that it is preserved for future readers of SO. Oh wait, there is no code in your fiddle.

Comment: @JayBlanchard there is no script :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/3yRhD/2/

```
$('.panel').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find('.glyphicon-edit.yellow').css({
        'background': '#FFFF00'
    });
});
$('.panel').mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find('.glyphicon-edit.yellow').css({
        'background': 'transparent'
    });
});
```

Naturally you could just target the elements with the yellow class, `.find('.yellow')`, but I was being specific here.

Comment: And how to apply a smooth transition fade with CSS3? for display none to display block?

Comment: You could create a CSS3 class with that fade in it and then use .addClass('myFadeClass') and .removeClass('myFadeClass') rather than using the .css() function above.

Comment: Where i add the ".addclass" In which line of the jquery function?

Comment: Remove the .css() method from the mouseover and mouseout functions above and replace those with the addClass() function.

Comment: I forget this!! If is each panel has an unique id, how can do it to hover in a panel of id 1 and only apply the class to the panel of id 1! Now the class apply to all my panels when i hover in anyone, i don't want this.

Comment: The function as written will only look for the icon within it. I did notice that there are multiple icons per panel, which is why I specified .glyphicon-edit. If you need it for specific panels set up a fiddle showing more than one panel and I'll help you figure it out.

Comment: instead of doing this: "$('.panel')" to find the element, do it by the id: "$('#panelid')"

Answer (score 0):

As far as showing and hiding elements based on hover, here's a css version to accomplish this. I forked your jsfiddle from your original question:

http://jsfiddle.net/a2z4p70k/

```
<div class="row hide-buttons-until-hover">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
      <button class="btn btn-success" href="#">
      Do Something
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the css for this:

```
.panel-body .hide-buttons-until-hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.panel-body:hover .hide-buttons-until-hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

(NOTE: after re-reading before submitting this, I noticed your html/css is a little different than your original question that is linked. The code below is for that original version...)