# Show/Hide icon in each panel on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a second part of this question:

[Display yellow square on hover panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269871/display-yellow-square-on-hover-panel)

I did it but now i want to appear/dissapear only work in the panel that you are doing hover, not in ALL. For now is applying in all because in the jquery code has the same class, so the show/hide effect apply to all the panels. Each panel has an unique id, so i want to show/hide the icon only in the panel that you are doing hover, not in all. (In other words, i want to do a jquery with a variable id).

UPDATED CODE:
CSS:

```
.fyin {
    opacity: 1 !important;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.fyout {
    opacity: 0 !important;
       transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.yellow {
 margin-left: 61px;
 opacity: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FF8F00;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
}
```

jquery:

```
 $('.panel').mouseover(function () {
      $('.glyphicon-edit.yellow').removeClass( "fyout" );
    $('.glyphicon-edit.yellow').addClass( "fyin" );
});
$('.panel').mouseout(function () {
  $('.glyphicon-edit.yellow').removeClass( "fyin" );
    $('.glyphicon-edit.yellow').addClass( "fyout" );
});
```

HTML (I only show 4 panels but there are a lot more):

```
  <div id="taskPanel" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div id="11" class="panel panel-off2">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">Task 11</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-id="11">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2">

         <input data-size="mini" data-id="11" data-on-text="on" data-off-text="off" type="checkbox">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">  
        <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <strong>URI:</strong>&nbsp;/cron/test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="taskPanel" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div id="12" class="panel panel-off2">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></div>
       <div style="float: left;margin-left: 15px;">Task 12</div>
 <div style="margin-left: 30px;width: 96%;">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow"></span>
<div class="miniswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="12">
    <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
</div> 
  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-id="12">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">  
        <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <strong>URI:</strong>&nbsp;/cron/test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="taskPanel" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div id="13" class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></div>
       <div style="float: left;margin-left: 15px;">Task 13</div>
     <div style="margin-left: 30px;width: 96%;">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow"></span>
<div class="miniswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="13" checked>
    <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
</div> 
  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-id="13">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">  
        <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <strong>URI:</strong>&nbsp;/cron/test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="taskPanel" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div id="14" class="panel panel-off2">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">Task 14</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-id="14">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2">

         <input data-size="mini" data-id="14" data-on-text="on" data-off-text="off" type="checkbox">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">  
        <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <strong>URI:</strong>&nbsp;/cron/test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need unique ID's for that. Use `$(this)` for selecting the panel you are currently hovering.

like that you can find the icon inside the current panel.. `$(this).find('.glyphicon-edit.yellow')` or whatever you want to add the class to instead of `$('.glyphicon-edit.yellow')`